# Why isn't my code printing like it should?

Tags: clojure, for-loop

I'm trying to create a for in Clojure.

I'm following [the cheats sheet from the Clojure site](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/for).

e.g:

```
(take 100 (for [x (range 100000000) y (range 1000000) :while (< y x)] [x y]))
```

I'm trying to create my own `for` which should print "Hello World" 100 times.

```
(take 100 (for [a (range 100) 
      :while (< a 100)] 
    (println "Hello World")
    )
)
```

For some reason it's not printing Hello World 100 times. Why not?

Comment: There are some good answers already, but I just wanted to point out that "for" in Clojure is *not* a loop (unlike "for" in Java or C).  It is called [list comprehension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension). It's used for constructing lists, not for looping.

In this case using `dotimes` seems to make most sense.

Answer (score 15):

The most important thing you need to be aware of, is that sequences in Clojure are lazy. That means the items in the sequence are only evaluated when they are needed. This allows you to work with infinite sequences.

Most of the time this is what you want, but it can be confusing when you are not really interested in the values of the sequence items, but in the side-effects of the functions that create the sequence items. In your example, the sequence is made up of 100 return values of the `println` function, that is 100 times `nil` - not very interesting. But the `println` function has the side-effect of printing "Hello World" to stdout.

The problem is, if you never do anything with the items in the sequence, the `println` functions are never evaluated and the strings are not printed. It kinda works in the REPL, because the P in REPL stands for print - the return value of the expression you typed in is printed. To print the whole sequence, it must be evaluated, so you see a bunch of "Hello World"s, but also a bunch of `nils`. If you run the code outside of the REPL (without using the returned value), you won't see the Hello Worlds.

If you're interested in the side-effects of your item-generating functions, you can use `doall` or `doseq`. `doall` forces the whole sequence to be evaluated and returns it:

```
(doall (for [a (range 100)] (println "Hello World")))
```

`doseq` doesn't return the sequence (it returns `nil`) and has a syntax like `for`:

```
(doseq [a (range 100)] (println "Hello World"))
```

Also note that you really only need to supply the desired count (100) once. The `range` function already produces a sequence with 100 items in it. The `:while` clause in your code is redundant, as is the `take` function (taking the first 100 items from a sequence with 100  items doesn't do much).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

try adding *doall* in front: The *for* function creates a lazy sequence, as does *take*. They may not evaluate until you add a *doall*.

This little quirk is a common annoyance in Clojure, but makes sense once you get more comfortable with "thinking lazily".

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is working for me. The last example *does* print one hundred `"Hello World"`, but the `take` gets just one hundred `nil`s that are also printed in the REPL. The first example works as it is:

`user=> (take 100 (for [x (range 100000000) y (range 1000000) :while (< y x)] [x y]))
    ([1 0] [2 0] [2 1] [3 0] [3 1] [3 2] [4 0] [4 1] [4 2] [4 3] [5 0] [5 1] [5 2] [5 3] [5 4] 
    [6 0] [6 1] [6 2] [6 3] [6 4] [6 5] [7 0] [7 1] [7 2] [7 3] [7 4] [7 5] [7 6] [8 0] [8 1] 
    [8 2] [8 3] [8 4] [8 5] [8 6] [8 7] [9 0] [9 1] [9 2] [9 3] [9 4] [9 5] [9 6] [9 7] [9 8]
    [10 0] [10 1] [10 2] [10 3] [10 4] [10 5] [10 6] [10 7] [10 8] [10 9] [11 0] [11 1] [11 2]
    [11 3] [11 4] [11 5] [11 6] [11 7] [11 8] [11 9] [11 10] [12 0] [12 1] [12 2] [12 3] [12 4] [12 5] [12 6] [12 7] [12 8] [12 9] [12 10] [12 11] [13 0] [13 1] [13 2] [13 3] [13 4] [13 5] [13 6] [13 7] [13 8] [13 9] [13 10] [13 11] [13 12] [14 0] [14 1] [14 2] [14 3] [14 4] [14 5] [14 6] [14 7] [14 8])`

For actually printing, you can try a more easy loop:

```
(dotimes [i 100] (println "Hello World"))
```

Finally, if you use `for`, you don't need the `:while`, as the range already has 100 elements:

```
(take 100 (for [a (range 100)] 
               (println "Hello World")))
```

Comment: exactly, the first example works and print it... but this example is from clojure site... I need create my own for wich must print 100 times Hello World... but It is just not working for me =/

Comment: What about the `dotimes` I added?

Comment: actually I must use For ... it must present this command to some folks... your dotimes works perfectly, but I need a code using for to print Hello World :X

Comment: Well, using `for` then, the only way is just how you were doing it. It actually prints one hundred "Hello World" messages. It just also returns the 100 collected `nil` values of the `println`.

Comment: (take 100 (for [a (range 100) 
      :while (< a 100)] 
    (println "Hello World")
    )
)

this for is working for you? I tryed here and didnt work out

Comment: @andre: yes, it is working. And also, you don't need the `:while` part.